# True or false: If $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ , then there exist distinct $a,b\in (0,1)$ such that $f'(a)+f'(b)=2$

Tags: real-analysis, mean-value-theorem

Suppose $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and is differentiable on $(0,1)$. If $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ , then there exist distinct  $a,b\in (0,1)$ such that $f'(a)+f'(b)=2$

I thought about Mean Value Theorem, but I only got   $\exists c\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(c)=1$. However, the differentiability and continuity of f don't imply the continuity of $f'$. What's the trick here?  Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate targets found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f%27(a)%2Bf%27(b)%3D2%24)